# Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080 when no process is using 8080 port

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, networking, tcp

I've been using Node over 2 years, never seen this case before. when I run `lsof -i tcp:8080`
,There's literally nothing used in 8080 port. I also tried `killall -9 node` and `sudo fuser -k 8080/tcp`
 but the stil same error.

but when I run my Node appIt occurs the error. No idea why this happens. any Ideas?

**app.js**

```
const app = new Koa()
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080
const dist = isProduction() ? __dirname + '/../views' : __dirname + '/views/'
const bpOption = {
    fields: 'body',
    IncomingForm: form
}

console.log("SIBAL")

app.keys = ['secret', 'key'];
require('./util/passport')

app
    .use(logger())
    .use(serve(dist))
    .use(session({}, app))
    .use(bodyParser(bpOption))
    .use(passport.initialize())
    .use(passport.session())
    .use(views(dist, { extension: 'pug'}))
    .use(routes())

let server = app.listen(port)
```

Comment: Does your app try to bind to port 8080 more than once? Some example code showing the problem would be nice.

Comment: @MikeC I just added the code, btw I just noticed that I get the error everytime, even in another ports

Comment: You're trying to kill 8080 but your app is also expecting a `process.env.PORT` maybe you have an environment variable that is making it run in another port?

Comment: @cinaroll45 I didn't set process.env.PORT this time.

Comment: Reboot your computer.  Try again.  If still a problem then, change `app.listen(port)` to `app.listen(8080)` just to be sure nothing else is going on there.  If still a problem, try `app.listen(10000);`.  If still a problem, then perhaps the error is misleading and you have a permissions issue.  Are you 100% user you're running this .js file?  `node app.js`?

Comment: @MikeCluck your comment was an eye-opener, was struggling with a similar problem. thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:8080)
```